# Cards shuffle in gridlayout when I Click on a button in the grid

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, grid-layout

This is my first time using this site so don't go hard on me

I'm trying to make my own card game and in the game, the cards are placed in a 6 x 9 gridlayout. Everything else I can handle, but there is one feature in the game that I'm having trouble on, and if I can get it to work, I'll be finished.  **This is for my final project and it's due in about 5 days**

I'm trying to make the cards shuffle when the user clicks on the White Joker card.
When that White Joker is clicked, the faced up cards and the other poker cards that are faced down are shuffled too. **I don't want any duplicate cards in the grid**

To be more explicit, I'll show my problem visually, because what I'm trying to do is complicated to explain in words and also complicated to make the code for it.

When the user clicks on one or more faced down cards, it'; look something like this:
[image: When cards are clicked Image]

When the White Joker is clicked it was shuffled and I don't want it to shuffle. I want everything else to shuffle while the White Joker stays in it's spot.
[image: When White Joker is clicked Image]

Here is my shuffle method code. Below I want this method to shuffle the JButtons but not the White Joker one. The White Joker one should stay

```
public JButton[] whiteJokerShuffle(JButton[] button)
{
    //shuffles using fisher yates shuffle BUT ONLY White Joker does not     
    //shuffle
    //FIX THISSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomCard;
    JButton randomValue;

    for (int i = 0; i<button.length; i++)
    {
        randomCard = rand.nextInt(button.length);
        //can't find a way to check for White Joker and make it stay

        randomValue = button[randomCard];

        button[randomCard] = button[i];
        button[i] = randomValue;

    }
    return button;
}
```

And again, **I do not want to see duplicate poker cards when I shuffle the cards and click on the buttons.** I keep making that happen every time I try, and I don't know how to fix it so here is my other code that creates the frame and stuff:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

/**
*
* @author elngo
*/
public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

private final int FRAME_WIDTH = 900;
private final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 730;
private int _attempts = 0;

private GridLayout _buttonMatrix;
private ImageIcon _image;
private ImageIcon _faceDownImage;
private JButton[] _button;
private ActionListener _listener;
private JPanel _gridPanel;


private JOptionPane _introduction; //this pops up BEFORE the gamem starts
private JOptionPane _endGameResult; //this ONLY pops up when the game ENDS

//using the Cards class
private Cards _cards;
private String[] _pokerDeck;

private JButton _whiteJoker;

final int GRID_ROWS = 6;
final int GRID_COLUMNS = 9;

//Constructor
/**
 * 
 */
public GameFrame()
{ 
    frameComponents();
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
}

/**
 * 
 */
private void frameComponents()
{
    _cards = new Cards(); //invokes Cards class
    String[] faceDown = _cards.getFaceDown();
    _pokerDeck = _cards.getPokerDeck();


    //makes a matrix of JButtons
    _button = new JButton[_pokerDeck.length];
    _gridPanel = new JPanel(_buttonMatrix = new GridLayout(GRID_ROWS, GRID_COLUMNS));


    _listener = new ClickListener();

    //places FACE DOWN cards in the 6x9 grid first
    for (int i = 0; i<faceDown.length; i++)
    {
       _faceDownImage = new ImageIcon(faceDown[i]);

       _gridPanel.add(_button[i] = new JButton(_faceDownImage)); //adds to grid

       _button[i].addActionListener(_listener);
    }
    add(_gridPanel);
    //shuffle poker cards

    //comment this randomizer out UNTIL I find a way to make WhiteJoker work
    //_cards.shuffleDeck(_pokerDeck);
}

public class ClickListener implements ActionListener{


@Override
/**
 * 
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{

  for (int i=0; i<_button.length; i++)
  {
      if (event.getSource() == _button[i])
      {
          _image = new ImageIcon(_pokerDeck[i]);

          _button[i].setIcon(_image);

          _attempts++;
          System.out.println("Attempts: " + _attempts); //delete later


          //***THE WHITE JOKER SHUFFLE PROBLEM STARTS HERE***
          if (_pokerDeck[i] == "WJ.png") //if White Joker clicked
          {
            //FIX THISSSSSSSSSSSSSSSsssSSSSSSSSSssssSs  
            System.out.println("White Joker found"); //delete later

            //save off Joker Spot so iterate through _buttonMatrix
            String whiteJoker = _pokerDeck[i];

            for (int j = 0; j<_button.length; j++)
            {
                if (_button[j] != null)
                {
                  //***THE SHUFFLE METHOD I SHOWED IS USED BELOW***
                  _cards.whiteJokerShuffle(_button); 
                }

            }
            _gridPanel.removeAll();
            for (JButton button : _button)
            {
                _gridPanel.add(button);
            }
            _gridPanel.revalidate();
            _gridPanel.repaint();
          }
         //***PROBLEM STOPS HERE***
```

I really need help on this. Just this one complicated problem, and once it's solved, I'll tidy up my code and I'll be finished.

Comment: A couple of general tips: (1) Don't use underscores (`_`) in Java variable names unless they are constants. (2) Don't hardcode the size of the frame. My screen doesn't have 730 pixels height. Let the layout manager calculate the size.

Comment: "*can't find a way to check for White Joker and make it stay*" You have access to the buttons representing the cards, why can't you read from the buttons what cards they are showing?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a modified version of the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (or the [modern version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm), designed for computer use, that was introduced by Richard Durstenfeld in 1964 and popularized by Donald E. Knuth):

1. When the White Joker is to be shuffled, you leave it on the same position.
2. When one of the other cards is to be shuffled, you make sure it is not swapped with the White Joker.

In the `actionPerformed` method, you iterate over all the buttons and then detect that the White Joker is clicked. The loop variable `i` contains the index of the White Joker, which you do not want to change. This value can be passed to the modified shuffle method.

To keep the example below short, I have passed an array of strings (instead of buttons) and determined the index of the White Joker inside the shuffle method:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GameFrame {
    private static final String WHITE_JOKER_CODE = "*W";

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        String[] originalCards = {"5H", "5C", "6S", WHITE_JOKER_CODE, "7S", "KD"};
        System.out.println("Original cards: " + Arrays.toString(originalCards));

        String[] shuffledCards = new GameFrame().whiteJokerShuffle(originalCards);

        System.out.println("Shuffled cards: " + Arrays.toString(shuffledCards));
    }

    // Uses the modern version of the Fisher–Yates shuffle, designed for computer use,
    // as introduced by Richard Durstenfeld in 1964 and popularized by Donald E. Knuth.
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm
    public String[] whiteJokerShuffle(String[] cards)
    {
        int whiteJokerIndex = Arrays.asList(cards).indexOf(WHITE_JOKER_CODE);
        Random randomNumbers = new Random();

        for (int cardIndex = cards.length - 1; cardIndex > 0; cardIndex--)
        {
            if (cardIndex != whiteJokerIndex) {
                // The upper bound is normally one higher than cardIndex, but it is
                // lowered by one when the white joker is in the range (to "hide" it).
                boolean hideJoker = cardIndex > whiteJokerIndex;
                int upperBound = cardIndex + (hideJoker ? 0 : 1);
                int swapIndex = randomNumbers.nextInt(upperBound);

                if (swapIndex == whiteJokerIndex) {
                    swapIndex++;
                }

                // Swap the cards on indices swapIndex and cardIndex.
                String swapCard = cards[swapIndex];
                cards[swapIndex] = cards[cardIndex];
                cards[cardIndex] = swapCard;
            }
        }

        return cards;
    }
}
```